# Many to Many using a associative model/entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've succesfully mapped a many to many relation using three model entities as shown above:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;
}

@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    private Calendar initialDate;
    private Calendar finalDate;
}

@Entity
public class Member {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)//idk if mappedBy is better or right choice against name="user_id"
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", nullable = false)
    private Task task;
}
```

The problem is that I retrieve a Task and I don't get a list of users related with it. If I map a set/collection on my Task entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="usuario", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();//I can use HashSet too.
```

I retrieve not a list of User's in first place, and the object retrieved is circular (points to itself 'forever').

What I want to do is to retrive an list/set of User's when I retrieve any Task object. Any tips? 
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean it is circular. That Task has a bidirectional relationship with Member is something your JPA provider should handle without problems, so what problem do you get exactly?  If you have a 1:M on Task, you can just iterate over the list and extract the Users from the referenced Members to form a new users list.  Or just remove the Members class and map the Member table as a M:M between Task and User

Comment: Only get circular when I add the second piece of code there in the Task class... What I want to do later is to insert a list of User's in my task... something like taskInstance.setUsers(List of users goes here); ... but when i try to retrieve this task I get a circular reference.
My main goal is to avoid creating a member instance for every user instance i have and insert it using a setter on my task, as list.

Comment: @Chris I've already done this, then I get a List of User's, for me it's perfect but since I'm using JpaRepository interfaces i cant create a \@Query because HQL/JPQL use classes and in this particular case I've removed the Member class, understand?